# IBOutlet in Python

Tags: python, objective-c, cocoa

Is there a way to use a Cocoa IBOutlet in Python? Or do I need to do this in ObjC? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This article](http://lethain.com/entry/2008/aug/22/an-epic-introduction-to-pyobjc-and-cocoa/) (found by searching Google for [“pyobjc iboutlet”](http://www.google.com/search?ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&num=20&q=pyobjc+iboutlet)) has an example. Basically, you create `objc.IBOutlet` objects and set them as the values of class variables.

Comment: Wow thanks! I'm a newbie to Python and this tutorial is just great!